# Maximal compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C_p)$

Tags: lie-groups, p-adic-number-theory

It is known that the general linear group $GL_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ over the $p$-adic numbers has $GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$ as a maximal compact subgroup and every other maximal compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ is conjugated to this one. (Unfortunately, I don't have any reference for this fact and so I don't know any proof.)

**Q:** Is this also true for $GL_n(\mathbb C_p)$ and $GL_n(\mathcal O)$, where $\mathcal O \subset \mathbb C_p$ is the integer ring?

Comment: A reference to the statement for $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is Appendix 1 of Chap IV, Lie Algebras and Lie groups by J-P. Serre.

Comment: Thank You. It could be that my question is really stupid, since I don't even know that $GL_n(\mathcal O)$ is compact. But, if this is true, I can modify Serre's proof to generalize the statement to my situation.

Comment: The unit group $\mathcal O^{\times}$ is not compact, so the group $\text{GL}_n(\mathcal O)$ can't be compact, as the determinant is a continuous surjective map from that matrix group onto the unit group.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, $GL_n(\mathcal O)$ is not compact in this situation. Further:

There are no maximal compact subgroups in $GL_n(\mathbb C_p)$.

**Proposition**: Let $F$ be any field which is complete with respect to a nonarchimedean value $\lvert \cdot \rvert$  but **not** locally compact, and let $K$ be a compact subgroup of $GL_n(F)$. Then there is a larger compact subgroup $\tilde K \supset K$.

**Proof**: $F$ being *not* locally compact means that either its residue field $\mathcal{O}/m_{\mathcal O}$ is infinite, or its value group $\lvert F \rvert$ is dense in $[0, \infty)$ (or both). In either case one can see (compare constructions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3280427/96384)) that the closed set $$ U:= \{x \in F: \lvert x-1 \rvert < 1\}$$ (the "principal units") contains sequences without convergent subsequences; hence, so does the closed set of scalar matrices $U_n := U \cdot Id_n \subset GL_n(F)$; meaning that there must be $x \in U_n \setminus K$. The closure of the subgroup generated by such $x$ is the subgroup $ X:= x^{\mathbb Z_p} \subset GL_n(F)$, which is compact and in the centre of $GL_n(F)$. In particular, $\tilde K := KX =$ the subgroup generated by $K$ and $X$ is compact.

---

Note: We used completeness of $F$ for the description and compactness of $X$ in the above proof. K. Conrad's [Compact Subgroups of $GL_n(\overline{\mathbb Q_p})$](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/GLnQpbar.pdf), which gave me the idea for that step, implies that the result is also true for $F=$ the (non-complete!) algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$, albeit for a different reason: Each compact subgroup of that is contained in $GL_n(E)$ for some *finite* extension $E \vert \mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: How would you describe $GL_n(O_{\Bbb{C}_p})$ as being special then? As the subgroup of isometries of $\Bbb{C}_p^n,\|.\|_\infty$?

Comment: @reuns: I guess so.