# Norm elements in locally compact non-archimedean fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

By a norm element, for example, I mean the elements $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that there exists $y\in \mathbb{Q}_p$, with $\vert y \vert_{p}=x$. In brief, I am curious about the set $\{\vert y \vert_{\mathfrak{p}}: y \in L\}$, is it always discrete in $\mathbb{R}$? I think these questions would help me to understand their topology better.

I know that in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, the norm elements have the form $p^{\mathbb{Z}}$. I have three related questions.

1. What is the form of the norm elements in $\mathbb{C}_p$?

Let $K$ be a number field, and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$.

2. What is the form of the norm elements in $\mathbb{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}$?
3. What is the form of the norm elements in $\bar{\mathbb{K}}_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Edit: I received a satisfying answer for the first three questions, in the comments. Now I have this question:

4. What is the form of the norm elements in $K$, when $K$ is **locally compact**? I think it should have a form like $c^{\mathbb{Z}}$, but I can not prove or disprove it.

Comment: @Mathmo123 For example, I mean the elements $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that there exists $y\in \mathbb{Q}_p$, with $\vert y \vert_{p}=x$.

Comment: Note that this is not really well-defined. The choice of exponent in the $p$-adic norm on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is mostly arbitrary, though choosing $p$ has some nice advantages.

Comment: Oh I see. But that depends on the choice of normalisation: for $\mathbb Q_p$, you've normalised things so that $|p| = \frac 1p$. But that choice is, although somewhat canonical, still a choice. If $K$ is a ramified quadratic extension with uniformiser $\varpi$, it would be natural normalise things so that $|\varpi| = \frac 1p$, which is the inverse of the order of the residue field. It is also natural to insist that $|\varpi^2|=|p| = \frac 1p$ to agree with the absolute value on $\mathbb Q_p$. Doing so changes the answer!

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks for mentioning this good point. Anyway, we can say, it has a form like $c^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 for example, is this set $\{\vert y \vert_{\mathfrak{p}}: y \in L\}$ is always discrete in $\mathbb{R}$? or not?

Comment: For a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, if $|\varpi| = c$, then the set will be $c^{\mathbb Z}$. For an infinite extension, it depends. For $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$, if $|p| = c$, then $|p^{a/b}| = c^{a/b}$, so you get $c^{\mathbb Q}$. If $K/\mathbb Q_p$ is infinite, but the maximal unramified subextension $K^{nr}$ is such that $K/K^{nr}$ is finite, it'll still be $c^{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I got the point, thanks for your explanation. That was part of my attempt to prove this fact: "Let K be a locally compact complete non-archimedean metrizable field. Then $\mathcal{O}_K=\{x\in K: |x| \leq 1 \}$, and $\{x\in K: |x| < 1 \}$ are compact". If this set $\{\vert y \vert_{\mathfrak{p}}: y \in K\}$ was discrete, then I was able to prove the fact. I have to change my plan.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3280427/96384) contains an argument why, as soon as the value group of a nonarchimedean valued field is not discrete, the field cannot be locally compact in the corresponding topology. It continues:

"For a field $K$ with non-archimedean valuation $\lvert \cdot\rvert$ to be locally compact, it is *necessary* that

- the residue field is finite, and
- the valuation is discrete (meaning, its value group $\lvert K^* \rvert$ is).

Both conditions are not satisfied e.g. for $\mathbb C_p$, and it's a good exercise to come up with many other fields which fail either, or both. -- An obvious third condition, which is met by $\mathbb C_p$, is that

- the field is complete.

Conversely, if a field with a non-archimedean valuation satisfies all three conditions above, it is locally compact. This is another good exercise; and a last good exercise is to show that such a field is necessarily a finite extension of some $\mathbb Q_p$ or $\mathbb F_p((T))$", as alluded to by reuns in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For $a\in \overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$ the $p$-adic valuation extends to $\Bbb{Q}_p(a)$.

$\sum_{n=0}^d c_n a^n = 0$ (with $c_n\in \Bbb{Q}_p$) implies that $v(c_n a^n)=v(c_m a^m)$ for some $n\ne m, c_n\ne 0$, whence $v(a) \in  \Bbb{Q}\cup \infty$.

As $v(p^{r/s}) = r/s$ we get that $v(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p) = \Bbb{Q}\cup \infty$.

$\Bbb{C}_p$ is the completion of $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$ for the non-archimedian absolute value $|.|_v$ whence  $v(\Bbb{C}_p)=v(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p)=\Bbb{Q}\cup \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It is very satisfying to me. But right now, my main question is about the locally compact case. Is it related to $\mathbb{Q}_p(a)$?

Comment: It is immediate that a field with a real valued non-archimedian valuation is locally compact iff the value group is discrete and the residue field is finite and the field is complete. Whence it is a finite extension either of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ or $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$.

Comment: I am trying to prove something else. "Let K be a locally compact complete non-archimedean metrizable field. Then $\mathcal{O}_K=\{x\in K: |x| \leq 1 \}$, and $\{x\in K: |x| < 1 \}$ are compact". I am a little bit confused and I can not prove it. May I ask it as an independent question?

Comment: $O_K$ is obviously compact because $a O_K$ is compact for $v(a)$ large enough. The valuation is discrete so $\{x\in K: |x| < 1 \} = \pi_K O_K$.

Comment: Also I don't see why you'd want to deal with such abstract things. (non archimedian) Local field = finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ or $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$, you **don't** need anything else.

Comment: Why $a\mathcal{O}_K$ is compact for $v(a)$ large enough? I can not understand the relation between local fields and locally compact non-archimedean fields yet.